# TSQL: How to change date if date falls between current year dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I  need to change a passed variable date if the date falls under the current year **Nov 1st** to **Dec 31st**

How to do this in TSQL?

Example:

Example #1

```
  @ip_batch_date = '2020-12-01T00:00:00'
    
  check @ip_batch_date >=' '2020-11-01T00:00:00' AND  @ip_batch_date<='2020-12-31T00:00:00'
    
  Then @ip_batch_date = '2021-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Example #2

```
@ip_batch_date = '2021-11-15T00:00:00'

check @ip_batch_date >='2021-11-01T00:00:00' AND  @ip_batch_date<='2021-12-31T00:00:00'

Then @ip_batch_date = '2022-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Comment: is `Nov 1` and `Dec 31` a variable date range or it can be hardcoded in the query ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have a passed in date variable called @ip_batch_date, off the top of my head I would use something like

```
IF  (YEAR(@ip_batch_date) = YEAR(GetDate()) AND MONTH(@ip_batch_date) BETWEEN 11 AND 12)
    SET @ip_batch_date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate())+1,1,1);
```

If instead of a passed in date, you were writing a query that was going to process *lots* of rows with a date column in them that you wanted to subject this logic to, it would be best not to have ip_date_column converted by a function, but rather to leave the date column bare and compare it to two constructed dates, like this:

```
CASE WHEN my_date_column BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate()),11,1)
                                 DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate()),12,31)
     THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate())+1,1,1);
     ELSE my_date_column
END
```

Finally, if my_date_column was a datetime or datetime2 column instead of just a date, make sure you you datetimefromparts or datetime2fromparts instead, and add the time in as well to avoid last day boundary issues

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME 

SET @Date = '2020-12-01T00:00:00'
SET @Date = CASE WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  @Date, 112), 4) >= 1101 THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) ELSE @Date END 
SELECT @Date

-- Output : 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 

SET @Date = '2021-12-01T00:00:00'
SET @Date = CASE WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  @Date, 112), 4) >= 1101 THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) ELSE @Date END 
SELECT @Date

-- Output : 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IP_BATCH_DATE DATETIME= '2020-12-01T00:00:00'

IF  @ip_batch_date >= '2020-11-01T00:00:00' AND  @ip_batch_date<='2020-12-31T00:00:00'
BEGIN
    SELECT datefromparts(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT @ip_batch_date
END
```